# Laravel+vue Getting blank page when run in nginx

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nginx

I created a laravel+vue project and when I run `php artisan serve` and load in `localhost:8000` it's working fine. when I load the project using Nginx it's giving me a blank page.

my app.blade.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>test</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/vendor/jquery-1.12.4.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/isotope.pkgd.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/slick.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.meanmenu.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/ajax-form.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/wow.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/aos.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.nice-select.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.counterup.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.waypoints.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.scrollUp.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/plugins.js')}}"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/main.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my app.js file

```
import "./bootstrap";
import Vue from "vue";
//import Vuetify from "vuetify";

//Route information for the  vue router
import Routes from "./routes";

//Component file
import App from "./views/App";

//Vue.use(Vuetify);

const app = new Vue({
    //vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    el: "#app",
    router: Routes,
    render: h => h(App)
});

export default app;
```

my index.php file

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

**when I add text into app.blade.php file that text show in the browser **

any idea what I missing here? thank you.

Comment: are all pages blank or only the vuejs?

Comment: only vue pages, when I add a paragraph to the app.blade.php it shows fine.